# How can I get j_username on my index.jsp after successful authentication with j_security_check?

Tags: jsp, glassfish, j-security-check

I'm using j_security_check on a login.jsp. The server is GlassFish Server 3. It all works, when the user is authenticated it then opens index.jsp. My problem is I need to get j_username in my index.jsp, but I couldn't find a way of doing it. All solutions I found are in Java and I need something that works with my jsp.

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 10):

The involved request  is in JSP EL available by [`PageContext#getRequest()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getRequest%28%29). The logged-in user is available by [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29). The username is in turn available by [`Principal#getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html#getName%28%29).

So,

```
<p>Welcome, <c:out value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}" /></p>
```

should do.

Using `<c:out>` is by the way not necessary, but useful for the case that the username could contain special HTML characters which could malform the HTML output like `<`, `>`, `"` and so on (which is a source for XSS attacks). The `<c:out>` just escapes them so that they get displayed literally instead of being interpreted as part of HTML markup.